# $3a4b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$, $3a4b \equiv 3\pmod{5}$

Tags: divisibility

> When the four digit number $3a4b$ is divided by $5$, the remainder is $3$. This number  can also be divided by $3$ without remainder. Evaluate $a$ and $b$.

We have two conditions as illustrated below

$$3a4b \equiv 0\pmod{3} \tag{1}$$

$$3a4b \equiv 3\pmod{5} \tag{2}$$

Simpiflying

$$3000 + 100a +40 +b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$

Which yields

$$4a+b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$

Here we get that

$$a+b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$

No clue whether or not it seems correct.  Could you assist?

With my best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4a+b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$

This step is wrong

$$3000 + 100a +40 +b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$
$$3000 + 99a+a +39+1 +b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$
$$a+1 +b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$
$$a +b \equiv 2\pmod{3}$$

Also given that
$$3000 + 100a +40 +b \equiv 3\pmod{5}$$

$$b \equiv 3\pmod{5}$$

Now what can you say about $b$ where  $0\le b\le9$ and 
$b \equiv 3\pmod{5}$

Comment: Can you explain this step: $3000 + 99a+a +39+1 +b \equiv 0\pmod{3}$?

Comment: I wrote $100a $ as $99a +a$ and $40$ as $39+1$  because I wanted you to see that they $99a$ and $39$ are multiples of 3 and 3 can divide them

Comment: Got it perfectly now

Comment: nice keep asking questions

Comment: How come $0\le b\le9$? What I mean is that I couldn't evaluate it further.

Comment: because $3a4b$ is 4 digit number try putting any value greater than 9

Comment: It's impossible due to $0\le b\le9$. When $b = 8$, we get $a +8 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$, implies that $a + 6 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$

Comment: ok you got it that b has to be equal to 8 and   $a +8 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$
you can write it as $$a +2 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$$
$$a  \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$

Comment: $a +2 \equiv 2\pmod{3} \implies a \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, $a \in \{3,6,9\}$ Does it seem correct?

Comment: Can you help me out? I still couldn't evaluate. a +2 \equiv 2\pmod{3} \implies a \equiv 0 \pmod{3} and $a \in \{0,3,6,9\}$. There should be other solutions.

Comment: a can be 0 as well

Comment: Yes, there should be other solutions. When $b = 3$, we have that $a + 3 \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \implies a \equiv 2 \pmod{3} $

Comment: I think you missed the point that $a + 3 \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \implies a \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, which gives $a \in \{2,5,8\}$

Comment: What did you mean? Aren't there two solutions for $b$?

Comment: okay my bad b can be 3 as well

Comment: No matter. I was just confused

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** If a number gives remainder $3$ when divided by $5$, its last digit must be either $3$ or $8$.

Also, a number is divisible by $3$, if and only if its digit sum is divisible by $3$.

By the way, $40$ is not equivalent to $0$ modulo $3$. As another hint, first condition restricts $b$ and second condition restricts $a+b$ (This is in case you want to use similar method for modulo $5$).

Answer (score 2):

You made a slight mistake. $$3000 + 100a +40 +b \equiv 0+a+1+b\equiv a+b+1\equiv0\pmod{3}$$ so we have that $$a+b\equiv-1\equiv2\pmod3$$ Can you do something similar modulo $5$?